# Flutter - error generating flutter app apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I've been trying to create an apk of my app, using `flutter build apk --release` in cmd, but I get this error every time I run this command:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':unique_identifier:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71871fd20009e8811e4cb86c0e32da7a\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
> C:\Users\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71871fd20009e8811e4cb86c0e32da7a\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

> BUILD FAILED in 4m 26s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     267,5s
> The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve
> the incompatibility.
> Building plugin device_info...
> The plugin device_info could not be built due to the issue above.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                            /

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19041.985], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add this line in your Project folder > android > app > build.gradle,

   `multiDexEnabled true`

inside defaultConfig.

2. upgrade gradle dependency in the android/build.gradle file: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' (previously on version 3.2.1)
3. Run flutter clean and rebuild your project

and also plz refer this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: I get the same error `unique_identifier\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:172: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.`

Comment: try this: 
try to change the compileSdkVersion to: `compileSdkVersion 28`
@Kaya Ryuuna

Comment: my `compileSdkVersion` is already like this

Comment: @Kaya Ryuuna there are multiple solutions given in this link, try https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/205